# Why does the lexical rule "VARDECL" can't match the text?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Lexical rules:

```
VARNAME:[_a-zA-Z-0-9]+;
VARDECL:VARNAME VARNAME;

DB:'[' '数据库' ']';
WS: [\r\n \t] -> skip;
```

Parser rules:

```
prog:dbOpen;
dbOpen:(VARDECL '=')?  DB  '('  VARNAME  ')' ';';
```

text:

```
bool bRet = [数据库](strOpen);
```

Error:

```
no viable alternative at input '[数据库]'
```

I want to match this text,how should I change the rules?

Comment: The first thing you should always do if the parser doesn't parse what you expect is to see if your token stream actually delivers the expected tokens. So iterate over the tokens in your token stream and print them to see if the are of the expected form.

Comment: Em...how to print the stoken stream?

Comment: You are probably using a BufferedTokenStream, which has a tokens property (as simple list), which you can iterate over and print the text via `token.getText()`.